# Alterar valor de variável após clique em botão em PHP

Tags: php, post, button

Galera, preciso que o `$i` mude de valor para `$i++` a cada clique no botão "Go".

Ou seja, eu clico no botão e aparecerá "1", quando clico novamente aparecerá "2", e assim por diante. Como posso fazer?

```
<form method="post">

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Go!">

</form>

<?php

$i = 1;

if (isset($_POST["Submit"])){

    echo $i;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então, amigo, do jeito que você quer fazer, utilizando PHP, não sei se é possível, a não ser que você passe um valor inicial do HTML para o PHP e faça uma requisição ajax para que o PHP processe este número, incremente em um e volte à view.

Eu não sei qual é o seu propósito e não sei se você realmente precisa utilizar o PHP, mas de qualquer forma eu vou postar aqui uma solução em javascript, pode ser que dê o resultado que você deseja...

```
<html>
```

```
<form id = "formulario">
    <input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value = "Go!">
    <label id = "resultado">1</label>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
    $("#formulario").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        i++;
        $("#resultado").html(i);
    });
</script>
```

obs: estou utilizando jquery... o stackoverflow não deixa copiar todo o código, mas espero que entenda...

Comment: Deu certo sim!!! Valeu rapaz! Acredito que dessa forma conseguirei implementar no meu código original! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar um campo oculto para manter o controle do contador e ir incrementando ele pelo PHP a cada submissão do POST.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="contador" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['contador']) ? $_POST['contador'] : 1; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Go!">
</form>

if (isset($_POST["Submit"])){
    $_POST['contador']+=1;
    echo $_POST['contador'];
}
```

Comment: Gostei da solução! Mas eu copiei o código aqui e não funcionou...